# Image quality is too poor in jspdf

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

Greetings!,

I am using jsPDF package for the ReactJs project, I have successfully generated pdf but when I am putting the image inside it, the image quality is too poor. I've tried to check my base64 code for an image which is giving the cool image as I need.

Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
  image2base64('Image/path') 
        .then(
            (response) => {
                result = response;
            const doc = new pdfConverter('p','pt','a4');
            doc.internal.scaleFactor = 30;
            var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,'+result;

               doc.text("I am header", 21, 10);
               doc.setFontSize(20);
               doc.setTextColor(40);
               doc.setFontStyle('normal');
               doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 150, 0, 445, 842,'null','NONE',0);
               doc.text("I am footer", 170, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 17);
               doc.save("test.pdf");
            }
        )
```

Comment: Can you try `png` instead of `PNG`

Comment: Can you try the comment mentioned here https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/762#issuecomment-399024074

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I am posting answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys Thanks for your help above...

But I've just used jpg image and it solved my problem. I think there was issue in PNG file.
:)